# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicolor

I get this error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" when I try to change color:

```
struct color {
    var r : Float
    var g : Float
    var b : Float
}

func setPixels(image:[color], pixel: Int) {
    let alpha: Float = 1.0
    let pixelView = view.viewWithTag(pixel) as! UIImageView
    pixelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(
        red: image[pixel].r, //Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
        green: image[pixel].g,
        blue: image[pixel].b,
        alpha: alpha)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float it is not the same as CGFloat. You have to pass a CGFloat to the UIColor. Note: You should name your structs starting with a capital letter.

```
struct Color {
    let r: CGFloat
    let g: CGFloat
    let b: CGFloat
}

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    func setPixels(image: [Color], pixel: Int) {
        let alpha: CGFloat = 1
        let pixelView = view.viewWithTag(pixel) as! UIImageView
        pixelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(
            red: image[pixel].r,
            green: image[pixel].g,
            blue: image[pixel].b,
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }
}
```